# Compile errors using PST SDK

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I am porting a project from Windows to Linux/Ubuntu, which involves using open software called "PST SDK"
(http://pstsdk.codeplex.com) written in c++.  This has not been updated since 2010 but it works fine in
Windows and supposedly works/did work in Linux.  I set up a demo program with nothing more than including
the header files (the library is all headers, nothing to link).  I had a lot of errors but got them
fixed by using g++ instead of gcc, and fiddling with the location of the library files and required
boost files.

However once I tried making some calls, I ran into problems.  I got a few things working, but the
following code:

```
std::vector<pstsdk::folder> folderlist;
folderlist.push_back(folder);
```

causes this compile error:

> error: 'pstsdk::property_bag& pstsdk::property_bag::operator=(const pstsdk::property_bag&)' is private

(There is a lot of other veribiage about what was instantiated from what file).  Here is the compile command:

```
g++ -c -I/usr/local/include -Iboost_1_46_1 -Ipstsdk -I/usr/local/include/mysql ostdemo.cpp
```

It is specifically the push_back call causing the errors - take that out and they go away.  Of course
that is critical to the working of my program.  Any idea what this could be?  I assume it has
something to do with my compiler version or switches, but I can't figure it out.  I am not much of
a c++ programmer so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `vector::push_back()` requires that the type is `copy-assignable`.  Obviously, your `pstsdk::folder` is not copy-assignable due to the assignment operator being `private`.

What are the requirements for a type to be placed in a vector?  It depends on whether you're using pre-C++11 or C++11, plus what operations you plan to do on these types.  See here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Pay attention to `CopyAssignable`, `CopyConstructible`, `MoveAssignable` and `MoveConstructible`

So the case of it working with Windows as opposed to Linux:

Remember that "Windows" and "Linux" are not C++ compilers.  You need to expand on this and tell us what version of the g++ compiler you're using on each OS.

Comment: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: Linux:gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5); Windows: MSVC 10.  One of the messages I get is a #pragma message: "C++0x rvalue references not supported; consider updating your compiler". It seems unlikely that I need to update the compiler since this library was working 4 years ago - I think I just need the right switch but I don't know what it is...

Comment: The bottom line seems to be that the type should never have been placed in a vector, due to 1) vector's copy requirements and 2) the author's intent on making copying impossible by making the copy-assignment `private`.  There is a reason why the author made the item non-copyable, but you "broke the contract" by placing that type in a container that requires the type to be copyable.  You should consider using a vector of smart pointers as opposed to objects.